# Excel search for a string and then return a value from a list based on the match

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I have a list of values in one table (Artist), that I then want to find a partial match to be used to populate a second value (Genre) from a separate table. If it cannot find a match, then leave the field blank e.g.

The searchable value and the result value
| Artist          | Genre          |
| --------        | -------------- |
| Nick Cave       |                |
| Kylie Minogue   |                |
| Carter USM      |                |
| Queen           |                |
| Smiths          |                |

Lookup Table for Genre results
| Artist    | Genre       |
| --------  | ----------- |
| Cave      | Alternative |
| Minogue   | Trash       |
| USM       | Punk        |
| Smiths    | Alternative |

Will populate the first table
| Artist       | Genre       |
| --------     | ----------- |
| Nick Cave    | Alternative |
| Kylie Minogue| Trash       |
| Carter USM   | Punk        |
| Queen        |             |
| Smiths       | Alternative |

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$10:$B$13,MATCH(TRUE,SEARCH($A$10:$A$13,A2)>0,0)),"")
```

[image: Artists]

If your data and lookup table are in different columns, you can use extended ranges, but using entire columns as ranges slows down formulas and is not recommended.
I've added blank text `$E:$E&""` so that zeros aren't displayed in the result.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E&"",MATCH(TRUE,SEARCH($D:$D,A2)>0,0)),"")
```

[image: Artists2]

Comment: Thanks?  This works for the most part as it need to match partially to a string of text no matter where it is in the Artist col. e.g. CarterUSM also needs to return Punk as well.
When I try this though, if I extend the range e.g. for INDEX and SEARCH to refer to cols e.g. $B:$B and $A:$A respectively or extend the range rows & not have to update the formula, then it produces incorrect returned values for any Artist not in the list used for SEARCH i.e. Column A.  Can this be avoid as I don't like restricted ranges as you always forget to extend the formulas then the results may be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula below. It split the artist's name by the space character, then look for the surname (last part of the name). If there is no space character in the name, it returns the name as is. It then search the value in the lookup table. If found, it returns the genre. If not, a blank value is shown.

```
=XLOOKUP(TEXTAFTER(A2," ",,1,0,A2),$A$10:$A$13,$B$10:$B$13,"",0)
```

Adapt the formula to suit your workbook/range.

[image]